# Enforce the precision in datetime column

Tags: .net, sql-server, dapper

How can I set the precision in `datetime` SQL column so that the value stored is always `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` i.e. without any fractional seconds?

I am using .NET and Dapper to insert values and although I know that in .NET there is no fractional second I am seeing in the database thats values have fractional seconds.

Comment: Use [DateTime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: "I know that in .NET there is no fractional second I am seeing in DB the values have fractional second" that shouldn't happen. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: Sorry - I mean in my application there is no fractional second in the .NET code

Comment: Nothing will magically add fractions of a second to your datetime - you need to investigate further.

Comment: Most likely, in your .NET code, the way you observe or inspect the DateTime values hide the fractional seconds by default, so they are most likely there all along, you're just not seeing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `datetime2(0)` there are no milliseconds

**Example**

```
Select NoMS   = convert(datetime2(0),getDate())
      ,WithMS = convert(datetime2(3),getDate())
```

**Returns**

```
NoMS                   WithMS
2020-06-18 20:06:21    2020-06-18 20:06:21.337
```

**EDIT: Just a word of caution:**

`datetime2()` will round up

**For Example**

```
Select NoMS   = convert(datetime2(0),'2020-06-19 07:33:57.500')
      ,WithMS = convert(datetime2(4),'2020-06-19 07:33:57.500')
```

**Returns**

```
NoMS                 WithMS
2020-06-19 07:33:58  2020-06-19 07:33:57.5000
```

Notice 58 seconds vs 57.5000